# jQuery load function hang issue

Tags: jquery

I'm loading a page which is 50 kb in size and it has a webservice call inside it. The issue what I am facing here is, during the initial load it takes considerable amount of time and there is a slight hang before the page gets rendered.

How to overcome this?. Otherwise is there any alternate available for the load function which can perform better?

Comment: When you say load, are you using the jQuery.load function during the call on the page to load this webservice call via AJAX? Or are you saying you're calling a webservice during the initial rendering of your page?

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly, the loading of your page is dependant upon this web service which is effectively your bottle neck.

You basically have two options.

**Option 1 - Caching**

If the web service you're calling does not have to be 100% up to date on every load, you could potentially cache the response. I don't know how you're doing it at the moment, but if it's a third party service, you could write a short proxy program to call it every minute and save the response to disk, where your page will then pick it up from.

Alternatively, if you don't want to write your own proxy service, you could use something like Squid which can cache internal network connections, so if your application queried something through Squid, it would cache the response to that server for *t* time period.

**Option 2 - AJAX**

If it's something that can not be cached (i.e. something to do with membership details on a webpage) you could look at loading the page asynchronously with jQuery.

Rather than load the details of the webservice pre-rendering you can use the $.ajax(); function to load it and then update your page with JavaScript once it's fully loaded.

If it's third party on a different domain, you would have to build a proxy on your own system so that you could call your site's AJAX URL, which would then call the web service.

Out of the two of them, I would seriously consider going for Option 1 if you can. Caching the response would speed up your application a lot and would reduce the stress put on the web service if it's a high traffic application.

Option 2 is still good, and it's used by lots of big brands like Amazon to cope with these issues.